How to run python script that uses pytorch from matlab?
I have a deep learning python module which I would like to call from a matlab program. I tried using pyrunfile() but I get:
 Python Error: RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid(s) 12136, 18172) exited unexpectedly

I cant get it to work. The only workaround that worked for me was to create a .bat file that calls my python module and then calling the .bat file from matlab. This solution is very slow because it requires me to write my output to a file and then read it from the file.
Is there any way to fix this?
